# IOS - Quartzcore custom UIView with shadow

Tags: ios, uiview, nib, shadow, quartz-core

I'm implementing a custom UIView to display inside a UIScrollview. The thing is that I need the view to drop a shadow so I did:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@implementation CustomView

-(void)setupView{


  self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
  self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
  self.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
  self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(.6f, .6f);
  self.layer.cornerRadius = 2;

  [...]

}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
  if((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])){
    [self setupView];
  }

  return self;
}

[...]
```

The point is that when I build and run this the scrollview is so slow and I just need to remove those lines where I was hacking the "self.layer" and The scrollview goes fast and smooth again.

**whats the proper way to add shadows to my custom View?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the all the redrawing that the `UIView` has to do when moving.

If you rasterize the layer it will become way smoother, this should do the trick:

```
self.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

You could try to add a shadow path:

```
self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
```

This might help a bit more.

Comment: This is a way smoother but still not fluid. There's anything I could do after this?

Comment: Not really, this rasterizers the layer (turing it in to a image) which is then moved and no longer redrawn when you it. On what kind of device are you testing your app ? changed my answer to include the shadow path.

Comment: Ok It's kind of strange.. IPhone4

Comment: should be smooth enough on the iPhone 4, are you doning any thing else when scrolling? Als make sure that there aren't any view in the scrollview that aren't visible.

Comment: I added [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds].CGPath and its fluid but i cant see the shadow =)

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. This has always helped me.

Comment: Well if I apply the shadowPath to self.bounds like you say I see the shadow but it's spreading all over the scrollview frame. This is kinda ok cause I'm adding a nib inside my custom View (  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AlbumCoverView" owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:self.view];)

Comment: So I had to apply the bezierPathWithRect to self.view.bounds..and now is working as a charme! thanks @rckoenes I own you a coffea =)